# Lwjgl applet loader crash, RuntimeExceptoin: java.lang.Reflect.InvocationException

Tags: java, swing, applet, lwjgl, slick2d

I am trying to run my LWJGL applet and I get these error's no idea what this means.

This is an screenshot of my file hierarchy.

[image: File hierarchy]

This is my the content of my html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AppletLoader</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <applet code="org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader" archive="lwjgl_util_applet.jar, lzma.jar" codebase="." width="347" height="355">

    <!-- The following tags are mandatory -->

    <!-- Name of Applet, will be used as name of directory it is saved in, and will uniquely identify it in cache -->
    <param name="al_title" value="Sudoku">

    <!-- Main Applet Class -->
    <param name="al_main" value="sud.main.MainClass">

    <!-- logo to paint while loading, will be centered -->
    <!--param name="al_logo" value="appletlogo.png">

   <!-- progressbar to paint while loading. Will be painted on top of logo, width clipped to percentage done -->
    <!--param name="al_progressbar" value="appletprogress.gif">

   <!-- List of Jars to add to classpath -->
    <param name="al_jars" value="sudoku.jar, lwjgl_applet.jar.pack.lzma, lwjgl.jar.pack.lzma, jinput.jar.pack.lzma, lwjgl_util.jar.pack.lzma, slick.jar">

    <!-- signed windows natives jar in a jar -->
    <param name="al_windows" value="windows_natives.jar.lzma">

    <!-- signed linux natives jar in a jar -->
    <param name="al_linux" value="linux_natives.jar.lzma">

    <!-- signed mac osx natives jar in a jar -->
    <param name="al_mac" value="macosx_natives.jar.lzma">

    <!-- signed solaris natives jar in a jar -->
    <param name="al_solaris" value="solaris_natives.jar.lzma">

    <!-- Tags under here are optional -->

    <!-- Version of Applet, important otherwise applet won't be cached, version change will update applet, must be int or float -->
    <!-- <param name="al_version" value="0.1"> -->

    <!-- whether to use cache - defaults to true -->
    <!-- <param name="al_cache" value="true"> -->

    <!-- background color to paint with, defaults to white -->
    <!-- <param name="boxbgcolor" value="#000000"> -->

    <!-- foreground color to paint with, defaults to black -->
    <!-- <param name="boxfgcolor" value="#ffffff"> -->

    <!-- whether to run in debug mode -->
    <!-- <param name="al_debug" value="true"> -->

    <!-- whether to prepend host to cache path - defaults to true -->
    <!-- <param name="al_prepend_host" value="true"> -->

    <!-- main applet specific params -->

   <param name="separate_jvm" value="true">
  </applet>

  <p>
    if <code>al_debug</code> is true the applet will load and extract resources with a delay, to be able to see the loader process.
  </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the error it returns.

```
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Users/Rose/Desktop/Applet%20Test/lwjgl_util_applet.jar, version: null]
basic: exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.defineClassHelper(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadAllowedCodebases(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.getProtectionDomain(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 18 more
Ignored exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1cb8654
security: Reset deny session certificate store
```

Ask me anything that is needed to be asked.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same crash as you.  Switching over to use JNLP fixed it:

(1) Create a JNLP file for your applet. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html.  If/when you make changes to your applet, you may need to clear the JNLP cache to get them to take (execute "javaws -uninstall" at a command line).

(2) Change the  tag to use the jnlp_href tag instead of the archive and codebase tags. Point it to the .jnlp file you created in (1).  See:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html

This fixed the crash for us. Note that in the attempt to fix the crash, we also updated the manifest file to use the Codebase, Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase, Caller-Allowable-Codebase and Permissions fields. But the crash still happened until we switched over to using JNLP.